# python: send UDP message

Tags: sockets, udp

I have the following challenge sending UDP packet:
The packet is 40 bytes long where all fields constant except some counter and checksum.

```
header='\xaf\x18\x25\x25'
message= 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRTSUVXYZ0123456'
i=1

#do some checksum calculation and store result into the checksum variable

message=header + chr(i) + data + chr(checksum >>8) + chr(checksum & 0xFF)
sock.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), (DST_IP, int(DST_PORT)))
```

However, looking into a wireshark, I can see that the message is 43 bytes where i have a 0xC2 at first location instead of the actual header 1st byte and 0XC3 and 0xC2 before the checksums MSB & LSB (which are the 3 extra bytes)

Any ssugestion what is the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

changed the encoding solved the issue

```
sock.sendto(message.encode('charmap'), (DST_IP, int(DST_PORT)))
```